# MomentJS like functionality for Android Apps

Tags: android

I have a record with date and time, and I would want to convert the transaction date from current date, differentiate and show number of days.

For e.g.

If the the record has got a date time, which is 1  hours before than Now, the system should show an hour ago...

Similarly if there is a record with 3 days before then instead of showing a date, I would want to show "3 days ago".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need to use any custom solution.

You can use `android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString`

> It returns a string describing 'time' as a time relative to 'now'.

reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html